# In PHP, after using .innerhtml to display an error message I lose input data, how to stop

Tags: javascript, php, html

After a user submits a registration page I do a check for empty **required** input fields. If a required input box is empty I send a message back via .innerHTML before I process the page. The message appears but any inputted data that IS there, vanishes. How do I keep that data on the screen so the user doesn't have to re-enter it all again?

```
echo <<<_END
<form method = 'POST' action = ''>
<span id = 'fnlbl'> First Name :
</span>
<input type="text" name="regfnme" maxlength="15" value = "">
</form>
_END;

if($_POST['regfnme'] === '')
{
    $txt = '*First Name is required!*';

    echo <<<_END
    <script>
    document.getElementById("reginfo").innerHTML = "$txt"
    </script>
    _END;
}
```

Basically, you get the idea.

Comment: `The message appears but any inputted data that IS there, vanishes` show code and HTML ... I suspect you're overwriting the inputs when assigning innerHTML

Comment: You're not sending the message back "via innerHTML" - rather than do this this way, why not put the `if` statement _before_ the form, and you can echo out any error(s) in the form without javascript at all?

Answer (score 0):

Make it like `value= Session` instead of `value = ''`.

Answer (score -1):

Save POST values and load them along with an error message.

Comment: I've tried saving the $_POST['regfnme'] to $_SESSION['regfnme'] and then loading the SESSION variable back to the POST variable (value) but nothing happens.

Comment: You must be loading before writing html with value=''

Comment: Right before the HTML runs I do a $_POST['regfnme'] = $_SESSION['regfnme'].  Am I missing something?  Is there a 'value' property that should be there, like $_POST['regfnme'][value]... or something?

Comment: make it like value= Session INSTead of value = ''